# Ajax not reloading the jsp on success

Tags: java, ajax, internet-explorer-7, struts

**Environment**: IE7, jQuery 1.1 , Struts 1

**Context**: Making an ajax call to a Java method which, and the end, reloads the same jsp.

The steps are: jsp A -->request to java method-->doing some stuff-->ActionForward to jsp A, which is returned in the response.
Actually I'm doing this with a single request using location.href and it's working properly.

Now I need to handle multiple requests and conditions and the only way I thought was by using nested ajax calls with async:false, but that's not the point.

**The problem is ajax does not reloads the jsp like location.href does**. 
This jsp is just a smaller part of the main jsp, so I'm  not reloading the whole jsp. I guess I have to handle the response in some way, but how?

Call with location.href:

```
<script>
function myFunction(){
    location.href = 'path/to/java/method=with_some_parameters';
}
</script>
```

Call with ajax:

```
<script>
 function myFunction(){
  jQuery.ajax({
   url:'path/to/java/method=with_some_parameters'
   async:false,
   success:function(data){
   //nested ajax

   }
  });
 }
</script>
```

There is a similiar question:
[Reload a page after jquery ajax call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30181519/reload-a-page-after-jquery-ajax-call), 
but it didn't help.

Another: [How to manage a redirect request after a jQuery Ajax call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199099/how-to-manage-a-redirect-request-after-a-jquery-ajax-call), this looks better. I'm trying some things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I got the full html in the response ('data' in my case), It worked using

```
function myFunction(){
  jQuery.ajax({
   url:'path/to/java/method=with_some_parameters'
   async:false,
   success:function(data){
     document.open();
     document.write(data);
     document.close();
     //nested ajax

   }
  });
 }
```

Source [Replacing Entire Page Including Head Using Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4292603/replacing-entire-page-including-head-using-javascript)